# Aptana Studio 3 crashes as soon as I open a file

Tags: centos, aptana

I have just donwloaded Aptana Studio 3 onto my Centos 6.5 box.  It was a zip file that already contained the executable.  It started up OK with

```
./AptanaStudio3
```

but, when I tried to open a file, it crashed with the message

AptanaStudio3: cairo-misc.c:380: _cairo_operator_bounded_by_source: Assertion `NOT_REACHED' failed.

I ran

```
sudo yum install cairo-devel
```

and it ended with

```
Package cairo-devel-1.8.8-3.1.el6.i686 already installed and latest version
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same failure for me.
I resolved it by adding this boolean option:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.cairoGraphics=false
```

at the end of /opt/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3.ini